# How can we do AC analysis when CE amplifier input is zero?

Tags: ac, bjt, oscillator

Hi everyone I would like to make AC analysis of an CE amplifier circuit. The circuit is some kind of LC oscillator. I would like to obtain small signal parameters but in oscillators AC input voltage is considered zero. How can I find those values. Thanks.

Comment: Without posting a schematic diagram, it is difficult to consider your question.

Comment: Are you aware of the oscillation condition which requires the LOOP GAIN to be "unity". Hence, you must perform a loop gain AC analysis for the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

To oscillate, the circuit must be able to amplify.

This requires a well-defined and amplification-friendly operating-point.

Given the operating-point, the small-signal params are a standard exercise inn circuit analysis.

To have an output voltage (AC), some power supply turn-on transient or some random thermal electron fluctuations will occur.